# Перегрузка оператора ввода для класса двумерный массив

Tags: c++

Доброго времени суток! Думала перегрузить подобным образом, но такой код не работает. Подскажите, как исправить?

```
friend istream& operator >> (istream &in, Matrix &mas)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < mas.n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < mas.m; j++)
        {
            in >> mas.mas[i][j];

        }
    }
    return in;
}
```

Создала класс

```
class Matrix
{private:
int n, m, **mas;
public:
  Matrix (int n, int m) 
{
    int**mas = new int*[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        mas[i] = new int[m];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
            mas[i][j] = 0;
}
```

Comment: А что значит "не работает"?

Comment: @Harry  Программа никак не реагирует, когда я пытаюсь воспользоваться этим оператором

Comment: А как она *должна* реагировать? Вы вводите ей нужные данные? Приведите минимальный пример, pls...

Comment: Что такое "никак не реагирует"? Да и в приведенном коде вы нигде не пытаетесь "воспользоваться этим оператором".

Comment: @Harry  добавила код

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваш конструктор не инициализирует поля `n` и `m` вашего класса. Вся работа в вашем конструкторе ведется с локальными параметрами `n` и `m`, в то время как про поля класса (`this->n` и `this->m`) никто и не вспоминает. В них как был мусор с самого начала, так и остается. Скорее всего вам просто "повезло" и в этих полях оказались нули или какие-то отрицательные "мусорные" значения. В результате и получилось так, что циклы в вашем операторе не хотят делать ни одной итерации, т.е. программа "никак не реагирует" на ваш оператор.

И формирование самой матрицы вы делаете в какой-то локальной переменной `mas` вместо поля класса `mas`. Зачем вы завели эту локальную переменную в конструкторе? Если вам нравится сначала работать с локальной переменной `mas`, то не забывайте в конечном итоге сохранить ее в поле класса `this->mas`.

Другими словами, как вариант исправления кода конструктора: добавьте в конструктор инициализацию полей класса и уберите эту локальную переменную `mas`

```
Matrix (int n, int m) : n(n), m(m)
{
  mas = new int*[n];
  ...
```